# R diff() handling NA

Tags: r, na, difference

I would like to calculate the first difference in a variable if either the current value or the lag value is missing. The R diff() function returns NA if either value is missing. Can this behavior be changed?

```
data <- c(5, NA, NA, 10, 25)

diff_i_want <- c(-5, NA, 10, 15)

diff_i_get <- diff(data)

identical(diff_i_want, diff_i_get)
```

Comment: What's the logic that leads to 10 being in your desired output?

Comment: The logic is (10 - NA) = 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
data <- c(5, NA, NA, 10, 25)
data2 = data
data2[is.na(data2)] = 0
diffData2 = diff(data2)
diffData2[diff(is.na(data))==0 & is.na(data[-1])] = NA

> diffData2
[1] -5 NA 10 15
```

First make a copy the data to data2, set all NAs to 0 and then diff.
At the last step put back all NAs into the calculated diff.

Answer (score 3):

you can replace `NA`'s by zeros:

```
x <- c(5, NA, NA, 10, 25)
> diff("[<-"(x, is.na(x), 0))
[1] -5  0 10 15
```

Admittedly, this is different from your `diff_i_want` ... but I'm not sure of your logic. How do you get `-5` as the first element of your answer? Why `-5`? The only way to get there is to implicitly replace `NA` by zero. So if you do this replacement there, why don't you replace the next element?

Though your desired answer doesn't make much sense to me, it is possible to obtain it e.g. using `zoo::rollapply`:

```
# first define a function that takes a vector of length 2
# ... and will output the difference if no more than 1 of the values is missing
weirddiff <- function(x) {
  if(any(is.na(x)) && !all(is.na(x))) x[is.na(x)] <- 0
  x[2] - x[1]
}
```

Now we can use `rollapply` with the window set to `2`:

```
library(zoo)
rollapply(x,2,weirddiff)
[1] -5 NA 10 15
```